# Me han encargado una tarea atreves de una función la cual no se como empezar con los siguientes requerimientos en python:

Tags: python-3.x, python-3.7

**Ejercicio 1:**
Realizar un programa que lea por teclado las 5 notas obtenidas por un alumno (comprendidas entre
0 y 10). A continuación, debe mostrar todas las notas, la nota media, la nota más alta que ha sacado
y la menor.

**Ejercicio 2:**
Crea un programa que pida un número al usuario un número de mes (por ejemplo, el 4) y diga
cuántos días tiene (por ejemplo, 30) y el nombre del mes. A suponer que febrero tiene 28 días.

un ejemplo de la función que me piden:

```
def sumar (a, b):
return a + b

def restar (a, b):
return a - b

def multiplicar (a, b):
return a * b

def dividir (a, b):
return a / b


def menu_calculadora():
print('1. Sumar')
print('2. Resta')
print('3. Multiplicar')
print('4. Dividir')
opcion = input('Eligir opcion --> ')
return opcion


while True:
operacion = menu_calculadora()

n1 = float(input('Introduce el primer operando: '))
n2 = float(input('Introduce el segundo operando: '))

if operacion == '1':
    resultado = sumar(n1, n2)
elif operacion == '2':
    resultado = restar(n1, n2)
elif operacion == '3':
    resultado = multiplicar(n1, n2)
elif operacion == '4':
    resultado = dividir(n1, n2)

print('Resultado:', resultado)


seguir = input('Desea seguir operando (s/n): ')
if seguir == 'n':
    break
```

Comment: ¿Y cuál es el problema? Aquí no hacemos tareas, por favor edita tu pregunta y reduce a un problema puntual, algo que hayas intentado y que no te funcione.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

para el ejercicio 1, lo puedes hacer de esta manera

```py
def media(lst):
    nums = [int(numero) for numero in lst]
    return sum(nums) / len(nums)

notas = []
for i in range(5):
    input_usuario = input("ingrese las notas del alumno separadas por comas: ")
    if int(input_usuario) > 10 or int(input_usuario) < 0:
        print('notas deben ser entre 0 y 10')
        input_usuario = input("ingrese las notas del alumno separadas por comas: ")
    notas.append(input_usuario)

print(f"la nota mas baja {min(notas)}")
print(f"la nota mas alta {max(notas)}")
print(f"la nota promedio {media(notas)}")
```

favor tener encuenta que en este caso solo verificas que las notas esten entre 0 y 10 una sola vez.

para el ejercicio 2:

```py
from calendar import monthrange
import datetime


tiempo_actual = datetime.datetime.now()
fecha = tiempo_actual.date()
anho = int(fecha.strftime("%Y"))

mes = int(input("Entrar el mess en forma numerica: "))
print(f'Numero de dias en el mes {monthrange(anho, mes)[1]}')
```

tener encuenta:

1. estoy usando `datetime` para obtener el anho actual.
2. uso la funcion `monthrange()`

La función `monthrange()` recibe dos parámetros, el año y el mes en forma numérica y retorna una tuple es decir una pareja de valores, como `(6,31)`.

El primer valor de la pareja es el día de la semana donde el primer día del mes cayo `(6 = Domingo)` y el segundo valor es el número de días.

En el código hago lo siguiente `monthrange(anho, mes)[1]` en este caso esto escogiendo el segundo valor de la pareja, es decir el número de días.

Comment: Gracias por la buena intención, pero por favor no le hagas la tarea a la gente. Puedes perjudicar su aprendizaje.

Comment: Tienes razon @Dante S. pero con la explicación que me das yo con eso indago y estudio el codigo

Comment: Ojala todos hicieran como vos... Así se podría ayudar a más gente.

Comment: Claro y la verdad hace muy poco estoy en el curso y el profe no nos explica muy bien el solo da los ejercicios y no nos da explicacion por eso recurro a esta plataforma

Comment: @Candido las aclaraciones que necesites hacer a quien te respondió deben ir o bien en la zona de comentarios si tal vez no son extensas o mejor aún en tu propia pregunta pero no en la respuesta misma

Comment: Si BetaM gracias lo mantendré presente soy nuevo en esta plataforma